# VueJs : Displaying pie chart data value of each slices

Tags: javascript, charts

I want to display the labels and datasets of pie & doughnut charts on their sides. I searched for many options on the internet including stackoverflow, but couldn't find a relative solution for my case. Maybe I missed something.

Now I have:

[image]

I need to display the chart data on its side like this: (For my pie and doughnut charts above)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I dont see any bar chart here. Second, what library are you using for making charts? If you couldn't find proper option to display label in that library, I can recommend you to use Amcharts, its more flexible. Let me know if you get your desired results

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I'm using chartjs for my charts. I couldn't find proper plugin to make exactly what I showed in image above

Comment: Have a look at amcharts, maybe you will find it useful

Comment: It was agreed to use chartjs in our project, unfortunately I can't change the rules because of one litlle feature. But, thanks for option.